# Visual Studio 2015 Error: "csc.exe" exited with code -1

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, csc

If I try to debug an application in VS2015, I Always get the error

`"csc.exe" exited with code -1.`

If I try another project (winforms/console application/...) I always get the same error. I previously had VS2008 installed for developing apps for WIN CE-devices, and I thought that might be the reason, but I already uninstalled VS2008, and reinstalled VS2015 (multiple times).

I have no other ideas what to do, did anyone had the same problem earlier?

Comment: I had the same problem. Executing **Build/Clean Solution** and then Building again solved my problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, let us know what you did to resolve...

Comment: Hello, actually, I haven't solved it yet. I'm currently working on another pc, when I'm back I will reinstall it completely (windows).

Comment: Restarting helped me.

Comment: Thanks for still helping, in my case, this didn't help either. I ended up reinstalling windows.